# What backend does the Xfce file manager Thunar use when copying files?

Tags: file-copy, thunar

Which utility does Thunar use when copying files? Rsync, cp?

How can I find out?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to use any command, and instead make use of some library which in turn uses glibc's standard functions for copying/renaming files

Comment: ... apparently `g_file_copy` either directly or via a wrapper function [thunar_g_file_copy](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/thunar/blob/master/thunar/thunar-gio-extensions.c#L708)

Answer (score 2):

Internal standard C code, most likely something from GLib. External utilities are not used.